# Nokogiri price doesn't show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Can anyone explain how can I retrieve the value of the price using nokogiri? 
The values that appear on the scraper that I created are the this

```
Costa Rica
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
India
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Indonesia
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Colombia
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Nicaragua
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Ethiopia
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Master Origin Pack (50 cápsulas)
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
CAFÉ İSTANBUL
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Envivo Lungo
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Fortissio Lungo
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Vivalto Lungo
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Linizio Lungo
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Livanto
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Capriccio
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Volluto
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Cosi
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Kazaar
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Dharkan
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Ristretto
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Arpeggio
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Roma
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Ristretto Decaffeinato
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Arpeggio Decaffeinato
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Volluto Decaffeinato
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Vivalto Lungo Decaffeinato
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Vanilio
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
Caramelito
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
```

My controller is this:

```
class CupsController < ApplicationController

    class Entry
      def initialize(name, price)
        @name = name
        @price = price

      end
      attr_reader :name
      attr_reader :price

    end

    def cups
        require 'open-uri'
        require 'nokogiri'

        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.nespresso.com/pt/pt/order/capsules'))
        entries = doc.css("article.ProductListElement")
        @entriesArray = []
        entries.each do |entry|

            name = entry.css('.ProductListElement__name').text
            price = entry.css('span.ProductListElement__price')


          @entriesArray << Entry.new(name, price)
          @name = name
          @price = price

        end
        render template: 'cups/home'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I'm receiving for each result:

```
<span class="ProductListElement__price"> </span>
```

which suggests to me that the prices are dynamically loaded by JavaScript once the webpage has loaded.

To be able to scrape dynamically-loaded data, you will need to use a library like [Watir](http://watir.com/guides/) which is supported by Rails 5.

With Watir, you are able to wait until all scripts are executed and all data is loaded before attempting to scrape the site.